# Mac OS X make doesn't recognize the private modifier

Tags: macos, makefile

I'm trying to write a `make` rule and want to suppress inheritance of a variable as described in [`make` manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Suppressing-Inheritance). I go like that:

```
$(my_lib): private LFLAGS += \
    whatever
```

When I try to use it, `make` complains it cannot find a rule to make the `private` target. Is this a problem/deficiency in Mac OS X `make` (GNU Make v3.81) or am I missing something in my syntax? (I tried it with plain assignment `=` instead of `+=` with the same result.)

Comment: Not that it's any consolation, but I just tried it on a SuSE Linux box and got the same error message there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `private` modifier was introduced in GNU make 3.82.  You are using 3.81, which is why you see that error.